# Is an in-vehicle, "smart" automobile-battery maintainer powered by a "smaller" rechargeable battery feasible?

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, automotive, lead-acid

Another naive question from a lay-person.
      A standard AC utility-powered Tender or Genius type unit is impossible to use with on-street parking. I am doubtful that "solar-powered" units sold would be sufficient on northern streets which are low-light in winter and tree-covered in summer.
      To put it bluntly, would common rechargeable batteries have enough "juice" to power such an application?
      Say, something like a 7-9Ah 12V (UPS-sized) SLA Battery, or maybe a more expensive (and bit more worrisome to leave unattended) lithium jump-start type battery pack.
      Is this feasible or economical?
      Would being DC- rather than AC- powered be a problem? (As a non-EE, my lay-person take on consumer electronics has been that a switched-mode power supply is so ubiquitous (because of usefulness and low-cost) that utility AC is preferred to power DC electronic devices - including battery-maintainers/chargers.) So would components and circuitry to up the 12.x V DC from an SLA battery, and to usefully modulate the A through the smart charging steps, perhaps be too pricey? (Never noticed anything like this on the market.)
    And apologies if my search terms missed a related post.

Comment: For how long of a period do you leave your vehicle parked? Have you had starting problems in the past?

Comment: Mostly technically curious if there was a reason why such a device isn't out there - considering the greatly varied automotive accessory market.   
 Personally, last two years almost exclusively consecutive micro trips, and sitting extended periods.  The 51R battery charge never quite catches up, even with an occasional highway trip. Battery tests fine. Pulled battery and charged it - great - but with same usage pattern, slowly coming back down. Alternator/charging works fine and no unusual/parasitic drain. 4-cyl engine has always started, even when open-terminal has gotten as low as 11.9 V.